# Oracle query to find out departments which have more female employees

Tags: sql, oracle

Given Employee database( id, dept, sex) I need to find the departments where the count of female employees exceed male employees?

I've been able to get the no of employees per dept per sex using oracle partition as below

```
select distinct(dept), sex, count(*) over( partition by dept, sex) cnt from employee order by dept desc, sex desc;
```

The result set from above query looks something like this--

```
*******************  
dept    sex    cnt  
*******************   
hr       M     1  
hr       F     2  
dev      F     1  
qa       M     2  
qa       F     1
```

I tried to join the above result set with itself, but couldn't make much progress

**I need to extract "hr" and "dev" departments as output as these departments have more female employees**!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Distinct is not a function (on a column), it works on the whole selected row. It's actually SELECT DISTINCT, as the opposite to SELECT [ALL]. (And "select distinct (c1), c2" is the same as "select distinct c1, c2", which is the same as "select distinct c1, (c2)"...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use aggregation and conditional expressions:

```
select dept
from employee e
group by dept
having sum(case when sex = 'F' then 1 when sex = 'M' then -1 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to find out departments which have female employees by descending order.

```
proc sql;

select distinct(dept),count(gender) as no_female_emp
from emp
where gender='F'
group by 1 order by 2 desc;
quit;
```